# Make dropdown menu go a little up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header with a dropdown menu, the problem is that when i hover on the buttons i can see the dropdown menu but when i want to click on any of the dropdown menu buttons it dissapear and if it's possible i want to make the buttons at the same level as the logo image : 
[image] , here's a codepen for the header : https://codepen.io/amrouhab/pen/jObXxOy
Also here's the code :

```
<nav>
    <div href="#default" id="logo"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/hxVf3lw.png"></div>
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Connaitre la CFTC +</label>
        <a href="#">Connaitre la CFTC</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Histoire</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Valeurs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Identité</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34 +</label>
        <a href="#">Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Organisation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Accueil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Rôle et définition</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Vie Professionnelle +</label>
        <a href="#">Vie Professionnelle</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Formation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Statut</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Carrière</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Temps de Travail</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Congés</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Vie Pratique +</label>
        <a href="#">Connaitre la CFTC</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Action Logement</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Pensions Alimentaires impayées</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Prime d'activité</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Apprentissage</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Activités +</label>
        <a href="#">Activités</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Actualités</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Presse</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Adhésion +</label>
        <a href="#">Adhésion</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Les + adhérents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Espace adhérents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Nous rejoindre</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Coordonnées +</label>
        <a href="#">Coordonnées</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Syndicat CFTC-FPT 34</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">UD34</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Fédération CFTC FPT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS :

```
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
  font-family: "oswald";
  src: url("fonts\oswald.regular.ttf");
  font-family: "lato";
  src: url("fonts\Lato-Regular.ttf");
  font-family: "playfairdisplay";
  src: url("fonts\PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.otf");
}

body {
  background: #d2d2d2;
  /* font-size: 30px; */
  /* line-height: 32px; */
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  /* padding: 0; */
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  font-family: oswald;
}

/* h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
  color: #FFF;
} */

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

/* h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
} */

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 890px;
}

/* p {
  text-align: center;
} */

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #302878;
  position: relative;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 15px;
  float: left;
  /* font-size: 20px; */
  /* line-height: 60px; */
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */
nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 180px;

}

/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #302878;
  position: relative;

}

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #28244d;
}

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #28244d;
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
  left: 170px;
}

/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li>a:after {
  content: ' +';
}

li>a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}

/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
  #logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }

  nav {
    margin: 0;
  }

  /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
  /* Also hide the  */
  .toggle+a,
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #254441;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }

  .toggle:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
  [id^=drop]:checked+ul {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }

  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 0 80px;
  }

  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    background-color: #212121;
  }

  /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #ffffff;
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
  }

  /* Hide menus on hover */
  nav ul ul li:hover>ul,
  nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
  }
}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

Thanks for all the help guys , i'm kind of learning HTML/CSS right now so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are learning html/css i'll suggest to not use float for the logo and don't use position absolute for the ul but learn flexbox or gridview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the dropdown menu not clickable :

```
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
  font-family: "oswald";
  src: url("fonts\oswald.regular.ttf");
  font-family: "lato";
  src: url("fonts\Lato-Regular.ttf");
  font-family: "playfairdisplay";
  src: url("fonts\PlayfairDisplaySC-Regular.otf");
}

body {
  background: #d2d2d2;
  /* font-size: 30px; */
  /* line-height: 32px; */
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  /* padding: 0; */
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  font-family: oswald;
}

/* h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
  color: #FFF;
} */

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

/* h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
} */

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 890px;
}

/* p {
  text-align: center;
} */

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #302878;
  position: relative;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 15px;
  float: left;
  /* font-size: 20px; */
  /* line-height: 60px; */
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */
nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 137px;
    padding: 43px;
}

/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #302878;
  position: relative;

}

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #28244d;
}

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #28244d;
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
  top: 0px;
  left: -40px;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
  left: 170px;
}

/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li>a:after {
  content: ' +';
}

li>a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}

/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */
@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
  #logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }

  nav {
    margin: 0;
  }

  /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
  /* Also hide the  */
  .toggle+a,
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #254441;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }

  .toggle:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
  [id^=drop]:checked+ul {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }

  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 0 80px;
  }

  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    background-color: #212121;
  }

  /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #ffffff;
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
  }

  /* Hide menus on hover */
  nav ul ul li:hover>ul,
  nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
  }
}

@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 94%;
  }
}
<nav>
```

Edit : Added the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
nav ul {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 137px;
    padding: 43px;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Try this changes.

Comment: That works thanks ! the only little problem is the drowdown menu is really far away from the buttons

Comment: added style for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div id="navbar4" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Abstracts <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a href=""> A </a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""> B </a></li>
                                                <li><a href=""> C</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="">Shark Tank</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>
            </div>
```